# Prime numbers and tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, primes

I am beginner in python and I am working on one problem which I am not able to solve.

***What I am supposed to do:*** create a list of tuples with prime numbers, the range is two numbers(which are also prime numbers) and the tuples in that list are supposed to contain only 2 prime numbers p and p+2

***For example***: given range (11, 31) returned list = [(11, 13), (17, 19), (29, 31)]

This is my code

```
def twin_primes(a: int, b:int) -> List[Tuple[int, int]]:

    list_primes = []
    list_final = []
    for val in range (a, b+1):
        if val > 1 :
            for n in range(2, val):
                if (val % n) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                list_primes.append(val)
    for val in list_primes:
        print(val)
        list_final.append((list_primes[val], list_primes[val + 2]))
    return list_final

print(twin_primes(11,31))
```

in the first for cycle I determine which numbers in that range are prime and append them to `list_primes`

in the second for cycle I tried to take the prime numbers from `list_primes` and append them as tuples into `list_final`

it tells me this :

> list_final.append((list_primes[val], list_primes[val + 2]))
>   IndexError: list index out of range*

could someone please help me with this? I think I understand that error but I don't know how to fix the code so it just takes the `p`, `p+2` into one tuple and then it would take another pair and so on... also it has to ignore 23 even though it is prime number.

Comment: What do you expect `list_primes[val]` to be? `val` is an element of `list_primes`, not an index into the list.

Comment: You should do some basic debugging first: `print (val)` just before the point of error is the "obvious" first choice.

Comment: Yes I expected it to be an element of list_primes and that is why I tried to append it into list_final....I thought this (list_primes[val], list_primes[val + 2]) would make a tuple of p and p+2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val` is not an index into `list_primes`, it's an element of it. You need to append a tuple containing `val` and `val+2` to `list_final`, but only if `val+2` is in the list of primes.

```
for val in list_primes:
    if val+2 in list_primes:
        list_final.append((val, val+2))
```

This can be improved using `enumerate()`, since it will always be the case that `val+2` will be the next prime if it exists.

```
for i, val in enumerate(list_primes[:-1]):
    if list_primes[i+1] == val + 2:
        list_final.append((val, val+2))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, now I understand where I was making a mistake, and I understood it was supposed to be == and not = :D

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for iterating over the twins is incorrect. `val` is set to the element in the list itself, not the index. You're treating it as if it were an index. You need to iterate over a *range* of numbers, not the elements themselves. I suggest using a range with a step of 2.

```py
list_primes = []
list_final = []
for val in range (a, b+1):
    if val > 1 :
        for n in range(2, val):
            if (val % n) == 0:
                break
        else:
            list_primes.append(val)

for i in range(0, len(list_primes) - 1, 2):
    list_final.append((list_primes[i], list_primes[i + 1]))
return list_final
```

This produces `[(11, 13), (17, 19), (23, 29)]` when a = `11` and b = `31`.

But your logic still requires some tweaking since this produces `[(53, 59), (61, 67), (71, 73), (79, 83), (89, 97)]` when a = `50` and b = `100`, and obviously this is not correct.

Comment: thank you for your commend, I ow understand better what to do